# Impact of not using ROLE_ prefix in spring security framework

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-annotations

what is the impact here if I use the line which does not have "ROLE_" prefix in the @Secured Annotation? Assuming that the spring security RoleVoter expects roles to be prefixed with "ROLE_" .

- @Secured({"ADMIN"})
- @Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
   public void sampleMethod(SampleClass sampleObject) {
       Operations;
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option will not be evaluated unless you have set the prefix as empty.

```
RoleVoter.setRolePrefix("");
```

Thus the method will not be secured. As you mentioned the default prefix is `"ROLE_"` for `RoleVoter`.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to understand the impact from security point of view.

Comment: Hi, if I use @Secured("abc"), will this append ROLE_ prefix by default and secure is as "ROLE_abc" or will it not work at all?